# print values that are continuously over an int for 50% or more of the readings

Tags: java, if-statement

In my program for an assignment I need to report whether the pollution level was continuously over the danger threshold for 50% or more of the readings, and if so, for what fraction of the readings.

Here is my code so far:

```
public void analyseLevels() {
    UI.clearText();
    UI.printf("Enter levels, end with 'done':%n");
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int dangerCount = 0;
    int input = 0;
    double av = 0;
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    UI.nextInt();
    UI.println("-------Analysis-------");
        while(UI.hasNextInt()){ 
     int  amt = UI.nextInt();

     if( amt > 0){

        if(amt > max){
          max = amt;

        }

        if(amt < min){
          min = amt;

        }

        if(amt >= NO2_DANGER_LEVEL){

          UI.printf("Dangerous level: %dppb%n", amt);
          dangerCount++;

        }

        sum += amt;
        count++;
      }


   }

   av = ( sum ) / ( count );
   UI.println("-------Analysis-------");
   UI.printf( "Average level: %.1fppb%n", av );
   UI.printf( "Maximum level: %dppb%n", max );
   UI.printf( "Minimum level: %dppb%n", min );
   UI.printf( "Level was dangerous %d times%n", dangerCount );
   UI.nextLine(); // to clear out the input

}
```

Comment: What is your question or problem?

Comment: @dunni , The question is "Complete my homework. Details in the title as well as in the description above the code"

Comment: the danger threshold it 120, and so when every value that the user input is 120 or over, it records it and prints it. I want it to print out if 50% or more of the readings are continuous, and how many of them there are, say 5 readings are continuous, i'll put UI.println("5 readings were continous");
I just dont quite knoe how to do this. @dunni

Comment: You already count the number of danger inputs and the total number of inputs. To get the percentage of danger inputs relative to the number of total inputs just do: `double percentage = 100.0*dangerCount / count;`

Answer (score 0):

This line

`av = ( sum ) / ( count );`

is not doing what you think it's doing. The division will be performed in *integer arithmetic*: any remainder is truncated

To solve, use

`av = 1.0 *  sum  /  count ;`

This will have the effect of *promoting* `sum` and `count` to floating point.

Comment: Of course, `av = (double)sum  /  count ;` will do the same without an additional multiplication.